# (PHP) Separating Arrays into Multidimensional

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

At present I have an array of data [0] - [574].

What I would like to do is split this down into a multidimensional array in 25 parts i.e. [0] - [22] as below:

```
Array
(
    [0] =>
        [0] => abc
        ...
        [22] => xyz
    [1] =>
        [0] => abc
        ...
        [22] => xyz
    ...
}
```

I assume it can be done using a for loop to split it all up - Ive tried a few methods but havent seemed to quite get there yet!

Thanks

-mango

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a built-in function for [that](http://php.net/array_chunk):

```
$parts = array_chunk($array, 23);
```

Comment: Haha, didn't even care to look for it :) +1

Answer (score 1):

I've just [used](http://www.ideone.com/OdoDa) dummy data, but you'll get the idea:

```
// Set up input with dummy data
$input = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 574; $i++) {
        $input[] = $i . 'aaa';
}

$out = array();
for ($i = 0, $j = sizeof($input); $i < $j; $i++) {
        $bucket = floor($i / ($j / 25));
        if (!isset($out[$bucket])) {
                $out[$bucket] = array();
        }
        $out[$bucket][] = $input[$i];
}

print_r($out);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array();
$chunks = ceil(count($array) / 25);
$new = array_chunk($array, $chunks);
```